# apache mod_headers use base 64

Tags: apache-httpd, reverse-proxy

I am currently migrating a reverse proxy which is using apache.
I have one application which need to transfert headers to the backend.
For this I am using the following in my conf :

```
RequestHeader set SSL_CERTIFICATE_SERIAL %{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL}s
RequestHeader set SSL_CERTIFICATE_DN %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s
```

It appears that the old reverse which is running apache 1.3 (need to be confirmed) transfert the header encoded in base64.

The same configuration with the new server which is running apache 2.2.21 transfert the headers in clear text.

My question is : Does the apache version 1.3 mod_headers encode them in base64 ? If yes can I reproduce this with apache 2.2.21 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this is not a apache related issue.

This behaviour is specific to rweb reverse proxy from denyall.

Old version 3.8 was using base64 encoding. They don't use it anymore on the rweb 4.1